# How to resolve 'Use not null pattern...' suggestion in switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

In Visual Studio 2019, trying to use some newer features of c#, specifically newer features of the switch statement.

I want to switch on the type of an object, and I've seen a few ways to accomplish this, I'm using this approach:

```
private string MyFunc (Employee q)
  ....
  Type qt = q.GetType();
  switch (qt)
  {
     case Type _ when qt == typeof(HumanResources):
         //some code
         break;
     case Type _ when qt == typeof(Sales):
         //some code
         break;
     .....
     default:
         break;
  };
  .....
}
```

I've changed class names and obviously am not showing all code. However the *case Type* has the squiggly lines with the following suggestion/comment:

[image]

I would like to implement the suggestion, but cannot figure out how. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't switch on the variable's *type*, switch on the variable itself and use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/safely-cast-using-pattern-matching-is-and-as-operators) to select the right case based on the type.

```
private string MyFunc (Employee q)
{
    switch (q)
    {
        case HumanResources hr:
            // some code
            break;
        case Sales s:
            // some code
            break;
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

You don't need to add a variable name (`hr`, `s`) in the case, it's there in case you need to access the variable as that particular type.

Comment: Thank you also gunr2171. As I stated in my reply to Woll, I was overthinking this. Either his solution as well as yours is the way to go.

Comment: I'm choosing yours, as in testing I see that using the hr and s nicely saves me a cast.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I do not experience that warning/error/suggestion in VS2022.

That said, I'd like to suggest you instead use the `switch` statement more properly:

```
private string MyFunc(Employee q)
{
    switch (q)
    {
        case HumanResources:
            //some code
            break;
        case Sales:
            //some code
            break;
         default:
            break;
    };
    return null;
}
```

So instead of operating against the `Type` metadata, you are operating against the instances themselves.  This dispenses with any need for the `when` operator and the code appears much more readable to me.

Comment: My gosh thanks, Your answer is much better, I was clearly overthinking this! ;-)  As for that warning, I have a plugin called Resharper to help with code suggestions so it's probably that plugin that's making the suggestion.